# Nested pound sign problem

Tags: coldfusion

I'm having an issue when I try to nest pound signs in my ColdFusion code. I keep getting the following error message:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 57 at column 26.
>   ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
>
> #

Here is the code:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="12">
    <cfset needRecord.setNeed#i#(#form["need#i#"]#) />
</cfloop>
```

If I run the loop outside the cfset tag like this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="12">
    needRecord.setNeed#i#(#form["need#i#"]#)
</cfloop>
```

The code runs and generates what I would like to generate within the cfset tag. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is needRecord a CFC? Here is one way to do it:

```
<cfinvoke component="#needRecord#" method="setNeed#i#" x="#form['need#i#']#">
```

Where "x" is the argument name for setNeed. You can also simplify. Something like:

```
<cfset value = form["need#o#"]>
<cfset evaluate("needRecord.setNeed#i#(value)")>
```

Comment: Typo in last line of last code block, move the final # inside the ).

Comment: needRecord is a record object. I'm using Reactor.

Comment: It won't change the execution at all, but with Ray's latter example you don't need the pound signs around the "value" variable: `<cfset evaluate("needRecord.setNeed#i#(value)")/>`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance. Using evaluate did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have pound signs in a cfset unless it is in a string (such as the "need#i#").  Note that for dynamic CFML you can make use of ColdFusion's evaluate() function.

```
<cfset cfml = "needRecord.setNeed#i#(form[need#i#])" />
<cfset evaluate(cfml) />
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you could re-write it as:

```
<cfset needRecord.setNeed#i#(form["need#i#"]) />
```

Pound signs around form[] should not be necessary and that should clear up the nested pound sign issue

Comment: Daniel....still getting the same error message but you are right about the pound signs around form!

Comment: must use cfinvoke or evaluate